# Author for each remote or branch

Tags: git, bash, git-branch, githooks

Is there any way to set different authors for each remote or branch in Git?

The only thing coming to my mind is scripting it using Git hooks (post-checkout/post-commit), which would check the current branch and change the author, but it would work only for branches, not remotes and doesn't look elegant to me. Are there any other solutions?

**UPDATE:**

I appreciate your answers, but why would you guys need to know the reason I am doing this? :) Anyway, let me clarify this for you:

I have local repo with 2 remotes: `remoteA` and `remoteB`. Also, I have 2 branches: `branchA` and `branchB`. Each remote is set to track those branches respectively:

```
git remote add -t branchA remoteA [remoteA-URL]
git remote add -t branchB remoteB [remoteB-URL]
```

There are 2 teams making changes to this repository: *TeamA* and *TeamB*. I usually pull commits from `remoteB/branchB` to `branchB`, cherry-pick or squash and merge some commits to `branchA` and push to `remoteA/branchA`. Sometimes I do merge commits from `remoteA/branchA` to `branchB` too. Now, the thing is - **I need commits pushed to each remote be under different username/email**. `usernameA` for `remoteA` and `usernameB` for remote `remoteB`. Currently, I just `rebase` after `cherry-pick && merge` edit commits with `commit --amend --author`, but I would like to somehow automate this. I know I could create 2 local repos and set different configuration for each, including author initials and push/pull between local repos. But I would like to keep this in one local repo.

You still need to know - why I need these all? Well, for personal reasons.

*After* asking question, I found, that there is `pre-push` hook, which would help to automate `commit --amend --author`, but this is just thought, I haven't tried that in practice. When I do, I will add results and/or code here.

Comment: Branches don't have authors; individual commits have authors.  Since branch labels can be moved from one commit to another, but the commits themselves can never be changed, the question as a whole doesn't quite make sense.  What exactly would you like to achieve with this?

Comment: @torek , I have repository with 2 remotes. Each remote has 1 branch. I need to push to each remote with different email/name. Another solution would be to have 2 local repos, but I already have 1 and would like to keep so.

Comment: @torek if the question makes sense to you, you should edit it to clarify it, because as it's currently written, it makes no sense to me either. Also, this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Cupcake: I wrote an answer that assumes a goal, but I'm still not sure that this is the actual goal; it seems like an odd one.  If that IS the goal then I might go back and edit the question later :-)

Comment: @Azamat what do you mean that you need to push to each remote with a different email address and name, and more importantly, ***why*** do you need to do this?

Comment: -1 because I think I understand the technical issue (from the comments, not the question, so your current question is unclear!), but I do not get the use case. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @FinalContest , if you don't understand, just move on, thanks for downvote, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: the question is updated and my original answer was meant for a different question.

Apparently there are:

1. two different remotes
2. two different teams
3. working two different lines of development

(It's not clear whether the two different teams push to the two different remotes, although that would make sense.)

In this case, the two branches are really entirely different lines of development.  If you cross them (by merging), you pick up the other branch's history, including commit authors.  There is no way around this.  If you do merges in both directions, eventually your two IDs will show up in the "other" branch.

The thing you need to understand here is that each commit records (indirectly, but indelibly) the *entire history* of the development that comes before it, through its parent commit IDs.

A commit-ID is a string (the SHA-1, the thing that looks like `badc0ffee` etc in `git log` output).  There is exactly one unique ID for every commit in the repository.  That commit ID *is* a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of the commit: author, email, date, list of parent commit IDs, text message, and source-tree-ID.  If you want to change *any* of these, you must make a new commit—a copy with the change in place—and you will get a new, *different* ID.

Because each commit stores its parent commit ID(s), you may start with any given commit and find all its parent commits.  Using those commits, you may find their parents, and so on.  This is what gives you the history of who did what, and when: each of those commits has an author (and committer), date, message, and attached source-tree.

We can draw a graph of these commits.  Let's do this with `branchA` and `branchB`, and let's assume they are very simple and linear to begin with:

```
A1 - A2 - A3   <-- branchA

B1 - B2 - B3   <-- branchB
```

Each ID (`A1` through `A3` and `B1` through `B3`) represents some long SHA-1; we don't really care about the values and they are too large to bother with, so let's just pretend we have two-digit SHA-1s.

Now let's assume that you decide to make a commit as user `A <A@A>` on `branchA`.

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4   <-- branchA

B1 - B2 - B3   <-- branchB
```

Your new commit `A4` records, as its parent ID, `A3`, and as its author, `A <A@A>`.  This can never be changed: it's part of the identity `A4`.  If you try to change it you get a new, different SHA-1.

So now let's copy the change made in `A4` to `branchB`, but under your other name, `B <B@B>` and with parent `B3`.  This is more or less the effect of `git cherry-pick` with an amend to change the author, or `git cherry-pick -n` followed by a separate `git commit` as user-B.  You get a new, different commit-ID, which I'll just assume turns out to be `B4`:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4   <-- branchA

B1 - B2 - B3 - B4   <-- branchB
```

Now suppose later you decide to merge (a real merge, not a squash merge, which is not actually a merge at all<sup>1</sup>).  A merge commit is simply one that records two or more parent commit IDs.  Let's say this merge goes on `branchA` and merges `branchB`, which have developed some more since then:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5 - M   <-- branchA
                       /
B1 - B2 - B3 - B4 - B5   <-- branchB
```

The branch-label `branchB` points to your commit `B5`, but `B5` points back to your `B4` (written as user `B <B@B>`).  The branch-label `branchA` now points to merge commit `M`, which points to *two* parents: `A5` and `B5`.  By following `B5` back to `B4`, and `A5` back to `A4`, anyone with access to commit `M`—which they'll have once you push `branchA` to `remoteA`—will be able to see that user `B <B@B>` did the same thing as user `A <A@A>` at pretty much the same time.  Furthermore, if commits `B1` through `B5` did not exist before on `remoteA`, pushing `M` will cause them to exist, because adding a new commit (whether by `push` or by `fetch`) brings with it all of its history.  Commit `M`'s history requires `B5`, which requires `B4`, and so on.

If at some point you merge a commit from `branchA` into `branchB`'s history, you will also bring in all of that branch's history.

If you never merge the branches, you can keep their history separate, but you make it more difficult for yourself to bring changes together.

---

<sup>1</sup>When you use `git merge --squash`, git goes through the normal merge mechanisms as usual to build the work-tree, but it does not record the commit(s) being merged, nor make a new commit itself.  When you commit the result yourself, it's just a regular (non-merge, single-parent) commit.  So it's not actually a merge: it does not get recorded in the commit graph, and git cannot make use of the recorded information to make a future merge easier.

---

[original answer below]

OK, I see from comments that the goal—I will paraphrase here—is to make commits once, with one author/email pair, but by the time they are to be pushed, have those commits get copied to *new* (different) commits with the same trees but a different author/email pair.

Commits with, e.g., author/email `A <A@A>` are then pushed to `remoteA`, and (the same) commits but with author/email `B <B@B>` are pushed to `remoteB`.

Note that `remoteA` and `remoteB` do not share commits and can get out of sync (if, e.g., one is down when you go to push) and it's not easy to have the two remotes talk to each other to resync.  (It's not impossible; they'd just have to do the same filtering you'd be doing here.)

[If this is not the actual goal (e.g., if you simply need to authenticate to `remoteB` as a different user, but can push commits containing `A <A@A>` as their author strings) then the rest of this answer is pointless.]

Overall I don't think this is a very good plan, but it can be done.  Here's the outline, with two different methods that have various pitfalls:

1. Make commit-copies at commit-time (with, e.g., a post-commit hook).  This assumes you commit exactly once and never have to amend or rebase.
2. Make commit-copies at publication time, e.g., just before `git push` (write a script that vets commits, copies them as needed, and then does the two pushes, for instance).  This is probably the superior method, although it makes pushing slower.  In particular it lets you replace commits that have never been sent upstream: you can still use `git commit --amend` and `git rebase`.

In both cases you may run into problems if one or both remotes have new commits that you must incorporate before `push`ing.  For instance, suppose `remoteA` (which will acquire three new commits written by `A <A@A>`) is all in sync now and you push the three commits.  They arrive safely and all is fine.  But now the copies you have made, listed as written by `B <B@B>`, are set to be pushed to `remoteB`; but it turns out that `remoteB` has acquired some new commits on its own, and the copies themselves need to be rebased.  Moreover, you might wipe out "their" changes (whoever "they" are that made changes that wound up on `remoteB`).  This *will* happen with the tree-reset method I describe below.

Anyway, to make a copy of a commit, here's a way to cheat.  Let's start by assuming you have a branch named `devel-for-A`, in which you make commits with author set to `A` and email set to `A@A`; and you have a parallel branch `devel-for-B`, in which you copy those commits but with the other author and email.

```
$ git checkout devel-for-A
... hack away ...
$ git commit -m 'new stuff'
```

Now to copy these to `devel-for-B`, we simply substitute in the correct `HEAD` during the commit, then swap it back:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/devel-for-B
$ git commit -C devel-for-A --reset-author --author='B <B@B>'
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/devel-for-A
```

Note that you can use `-C` to copy the message from the previous commit, but you must then also use `--reset-author`.  Here I've made use of the fact that `devel-for-A` names the commit just made.  This will not be the case if you do the copies later, en-masse, just before the push.  In that case the simple (but not very efficient) method is to use `git rm -r .; git checkout $rev -- .` to import the tree from the other branch to the current one (so you'd get on `devel-for-B` and then import commits from `devel-for-A`).  See the next few paragraphs.

If you're copying commits just before push, you would want to use `git rev-list` to generate the IDs to be copied (this is `$rev` above but you need some shell script code to use it).  To know which commits to copy, you may need to add extra references to keep track of the last successful ID pushed to `remoteB` (assuming you're doing the copying from the `devel-for-A` branch into the `devel-for-B` branch).  (I have not thought through all the details on this one.  The remote-branch label is updated automatically so you know which commits made it across, but you may not know which original `A`-branch commits they map to.)

If you're copying commits en masse, doing it with `git checkout` is overkill: you could read the commits into the index.  Basically, you need to do what `filter-branch` does (so see that script), but instead of rewriting the existing branch label (`devel-for-A`) afterward, you (re)write the `devel-for-B` label.

Comment: thank you very much for answer, didn't know about copying commits, though it seems more hackish than modifying commits before push. Yes, I realize that it will be slow, but it my case it is not problem, as I push 2-3 times per week. Thanks for explanation, upvoted.

Comment: Based on your updated question, it sounds like you can't copy the commits directly.  You'll need to use `cherry-pick` instead.  Although you can try to automate this, cherry-picks can fail due to differences in development lines.  So you'll still need to do manual conflict resolution, in some cases.

Comment: *It's not clear whether the two different teams push to the two different remotes, although that would make sense.* - No, 2 different teams don't know about each other, that's all it is about. That is why I'm editing commit authors.

Comment: Thanks for these details, it is helpful. Special thanks for `git cherry-pick -n` :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this idea does not make sense.

The author is part of the commit. A commit might be part of multiple branches. Which author do you want in this case?

Also a remote is only relevant when pushing, but you need to set the author when committing which is long before you decide to push that commit to any remote. There is no way to tell on commit time which remote you want to push that commit later.

Maybe you should explain why you are thinking of this idea. There seems to be a different problem to be the core issue.

Comment: Just found out, that git supports **pre-push** hook from v1.8.2 and [here](https://github.com/raven/git-prepush-recipes/blob/master/pre-push.sample) is the sample of using it. It receives remote name and url as parametr and I believe I could use this hook to check/modify commit authors before push, based on remote name and/or url.